# How to give an event handler to "object.data=svg"?

Tags: javascript

I tried to make an event that if user click an object.data='close.svg' than some event is happening.

So I wrote some code, and those codes were not functioning.

I don't know why.

Below are the codes.

```
<object data="img/x_in_square.svg" id="alert_close" class="alert_close" onClick="alert('asdf')"></object>
```

Why this happening? How do I make this functioning?

Comment: You have to handle the click event inside the SVG because it's a new "object/document"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("alert_close");
obj.onclick = function(){
  obj.setAttribute("data", "close.svg");
};
```

Good luck!